# Visual Studio and JMeter web performance tests are unable to find free machines on the self-provisioned rig

Tags: visual-studio-2015, azure-devops

I'm trying to run some web performance tests on a Self-Provisioned Agents that, right now, consist in 2 Windows Server 2012R2 and Windows Server 2016 virtual machines.

I've used the PowerShell script from  this blog post and I successfully configured them.

(https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2016/08/22/use-cloud-load-agents-on-your-infrastructure/)

Using the same script, getting the Agent Groups is returning the 2 agents that I've installed and getting the agent, as well, returns that everything seems to be correct (for both agent groups):

name                                 lastHeartBeat                                        state
 ----                                    -------------                                          -----
win-4sjg9us1m9g               2017-02-21T11:20:41.9332745Z            Free

Now, if I go from Team Services to Test -> Load Test and I'm creating a new Visual Studio test I'm able to run it successfully.

However, when using the builder I'm getting the following error:

Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException: Test run could not be started using the self-provisioned rig 4c6cd633-bf4b-4643-af30-08ce4d05bbcf. Number of free machines available in the rig are less than the required number. (Requested - 1, Available - 0, In-Use - 0, Offline - 0).

Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException: Test run could not be started and has been marked as 'Aborted' due to an error while provisioning test agents for the run.

This happens for both Visual Studio web performance tests (with a Cloud-based Web Performance Test build step) and Jmeter (with a Cloud-based Apache JMeter Load Test build step).

As for the infrastructure:
•VM 1 was configured as an agent using the PowerShell from the blog post above
•VM 2 was configured as an agent using the PowerShell from the blog post above and also set up as an Test Agent (by downloading the zip file from Agent Queues page) and was configured and added under a pool
•This pool was then selected as the default agent queue for the build containing the web performance tests

What I'm missing here? Why the tests cannot find the agent previously set up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can reproduce that issue too and I submit an issue here: [Cloud-based Web Performance Test issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/issues/3668), you can follow up this issue.

Answer (score 0):

We are also getting the similar exception while using the Self-provisioned agent.
Exception "Test run has been aborted and marked as 'Error' due to an error while provisioning test agents for the run."

We have setup this agent in on-premise
We tried executing Visual Studio test by uploading webtest file in the VisualStudio web access. We are able to see our self-provisioned agent in the list and able to pick it.
However it gets stuck in configuring agent for few mins and after that aborts with above exception.
If we stop the agent service locally - it is able to recognize and throw error stating agent not available for execution. However when the agent is available it is not proceeding and completing the test.
Do we need open any specific ports in on-premise for CLT to interact with on-premise agent?

Second question is there a way we can connect to this Self-provisioned agent from VSTS?
When we execute the load test from VSTS like this
There we see only Cloud agents get listed and does not list self-provisioned agents